# Can I say that, if f$(n) = 3n^2$, then f(n) = O(n^5)$?

Tags: asymptotics

If $f(n) = 3n^2$, then can I say that $f(n)$ has an asymptotic upper bound $f(n)=O(n^5)$?

While that bound is not tight, it is still true, right?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. $3n^2 = O(n^5)$.

An easy way to see this is to consider the limit of the ratio $\frac{3n^2}{n^5}$. You have:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3n^2}{n^5} =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3}{n^3} =0.
$$

Comment: Thanks @Steven ! .. The limit is for "little-oh" as far as I understand. As you have shown, taking the limit of $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, if the result is 0, then $f(n) = o(g(n))$. Not sure if the same is true for Big-Oh?

Comment: Its not the same as big-O, but rather it is stronger than it. It means that $f$ is *much* smaller than $g$.

Comment: $f(n) = o(g(n))$ implies $f(n) = O(g(n))$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Following the definition of big-$O$, consider $c=3$, and we want to show that $f(n)\le c\cdot n^5$.

Clearly, $f(n)=3n^2\le 3n^5=c\cdot n^5$ (since $n$ is a positive integer)

Hence, $f(n)=O(n^5)$.

As you have said, this bound is indeed not tight. A tight bound will be: $f(n)=O(n^2)$.

Comment: Thanks @nir shahar :) So if we talk about a specific algorithm (e.g., insertion sort) and say that it has a running time complexity in the worst case $O(n^3)$ is technically correct, but is not a good/tight bound?

Comment: @Jarvis Yep, totally. The more tight the bound is, the more useful it becomes (since then it would more accurately represent the runtime of the algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is absolutely correct. Why and when would you do this? You would do it if you are in a situation where O(n^2) or O(n^5) doesn't matter.

For example, you want to analyze f(n) + g(n) + h(n). And you found that f(n) = O(n^5). Now as long as you can show that g(n) and h(n) are O(n^5), it doesn't matter what they really are. So say you have g(n) = n^2 log n, you can say g(n) = O(n^5) and in this situation it doesn't matter - the sum of the three functions os still O(n^5).